# Rust 1.30: как использовать BitSet и BitVec?

Tags: rust

Cargo.toml:

```
…
[dependencies]
bit-vec = "0.5.0"
bit-set = "0.5.0"
```

main.rs:

```
extern crate bit_set;
extern crate bit_vec;
use bit_set::BitSet;
use bit_vec::BitVec;
```

При компиляции:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `alloc::Vec`
--> …bit-vec-0.5.0/src/lib.rs
…
no `Vec` in the root. Did you mean to use `vec`?
```

При понижении версий в Cargo.toml:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `bit_vec` \ `bit_set`
…
Did you mean `self::bit_vec \ bit_set`?
```

Оно сломано или я чего-то не понимаю?

UPD0: удалось заставить компилироваться, но я не вполне уверен в правильности решения:

*unit.rs*:

```
extern crate bit_set; // Для bit_vec ситуация аналогичная
use self::bit_set::BitSet; // С self:: компилируется, но я не до конца понимаю семантику.
```

*main.rs*:

```
mod unit; // Успешно подключается.
…
```

Comment: Именно Rust 1.3, который 2015ого года?

Comment: Упс. 1.30.1. Исправляю.

Comment: Еще нужен полный MCVE ошибки, потому что [так-то оно все работает на плейпене](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f9fd8698bebd4f1c73efc1e7372ef250).

Comment: Так, делая MCVE я понял, когда происходит ошибка.
Если код в одном файле, то компиляция проходит успешно.
Фэйл случается, если `extern crate …` и `use…` вынести в отдельный модуль unit и импортировать его в главный модуль с помощью `mod unit`. Однако это дублирование `extern crate …` в главном модуле убирает ошибку. Можно ли избавиться от этого, если в главном модуле крэйты не будут использоваться напрямую? Видимо, это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Покажи, пожалуйста, полный код с новой ошибкой. Я не уверен, что правильно по описанию понимаю что происходит.

Comment: Дополнил работающим вариантом, однако сомневаюсь в его правильности.

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересное сообщение от компилятора в первом случае. Дело в том, что, веря сообщению об ошибке, получается, что в `lib.rs` крейта `bit-vec` написано

```
use alloc::Vec;
```

Что должно вызвать ошибку, казалось бы, посмотрев на исходники и документацию liballoc версии 1.30.
Но это, кстати, не правда, потому что, если верить исходникам версии 0.5.0 на github там написано

```
use alloc::prelude::Vec;
```

Что наводит подозрения на то, что вы не поставили версию 0.5.0. Вообще, похоже ваша проблема была решена см. pull request: https://github.com/contain-rs/bit-vec/pull/51 (похоже проблема вызвана тем, что разработчики двигали файлы). Как создание внешнего модуля всё починило — довольно интересная загадка. Попробуйте установить последнюю версию Rust (1.33) как рекомендуется на crates.io и поставить последнию версию bit-vec.